# Bootstrap Modal Backdrop get darker?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

HTML

```
          <a style="float:left" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#memberInfo" href="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="table-link clsMemberInfo view"></a>


            <!-- Member info Modal -->

            <div class="modal fade" role="dialog" id="memberInfo">
            </div>
```

AJAX

```
            $('.view').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var view_id = $(this).attr("href");
                datastring = 'memberId='+view_id;
        $.ajax({
            url: "memberinfo.php",
            data: datastring,
            type:"POST",
            text:"json"
        }).done(function(info) {    
           // console.log(info);
            $('#memberInfo').html(info);
        });
            console.log(view_id);

        });
```

PHP

```
 $sql = "SELECT d.expiry, (SELECT u.expiry from upgrade as u where u.customerId='$memberId' AND d.customerId=u.customerId AND u.cmpId = '$companyId' order by expiry DESC limit 1) as uexp 
            from details as d where d.customerId ='$memberId' AND d.cmpId = '$companyId' order by expiry DESC limit 1";

            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            if($row['uexp']>$row['expiry']){

    $s = "SELECT d.*, c.*, (SELECT time from freeze where customerFreezeid='$memberId' AND c.cmpId = '$companyId' order by expiry DESC limit 1) as ftime 
        from upgrade as d, customer as c 
        where d.customerId = c.id AND c.id='$memberId' AND c.cmpId = '$companyId' order by expiry DESC";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $s);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

            } else {

  $s = "SELECT d.*, c.*, 
        (SELECT time from freeze where customerFreezeid='$memberId' AND c.cmpId = '$companyId' order by expiry DESC limit 1) as ftime 
        from details as d, customer as c 
        where d.customerId = c.id AND c.id='$memberId' AND c.cmpId = '$companyId' order by expiry DESC";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $s);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    }
      $expfz = $row['expiry'];
      $explode = explode(" ", $expfz);
      $expfz1 = $explode[0];
      $expfz2 = $explode[1];
  echo '
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
             <div id="example">
                    <div id="invoice" style="display:none" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center"><b>Tax Invoice</b>
                    </div>
                        <div id="company" style="display:none" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">'.$companyName.'<br>'.$companyAddress.'
                        <hr>
                    </div>

                <div class="modal-body text-center">
                   <b>Name : </b>'.$row['customerName'].'<span id="btnPrint" style="cursor:pointer; float:right" class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"> </span><span id="cmd" style="cursor:pointer; float:right" class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt">| </span><br>
                   <b>Email : </b>'.$row['email'].'<br>
                   <b>Mobile : </b>'.$row['mobile'].'.<br>
                   <b>Address : </b>'.$row['address'].'<br>
                   <b>Emergency Name :</b>'.$row['nameEmg'].'<br>
                   <b>Emergency Mobile : </b>'.$row['mobileEmg'].'<br>
                        <hr></hr>
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">                              
                                <span><b>Date of joining : </b>'.$row['joining'].'</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                                <span><b>Period : </b>'.$row['period'].'</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                                <span><b>Date of expiry : </b>'.$expfz1.'</span>
                            </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
                            <hr></hr>       
                        </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-center">    
                                <span><b>Amount Paid : </b>'.$row['paid'].'</span>                       
                            </div>
                            ';
                            if($row['due']==0 || empty($row['due'])) {
                                echo '
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-center">
                                <span><b>Amount Due : </b>'.$row['due'].'</span>                       
                            </div>
                            '; } else {
                              echo '<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-center">
                                <span><b>Amount Due : </b>'.$row['due'].' on '.$row['duedate'].'</span>                       
                            </div>
                            ';  
                            }
                            if($row['payment']=="Cheque"){
                            echo    '
                            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
                                <br>
                            </div>    
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-center">    

                                <span><b>Paid By: </b>'.$row['payment'].'</span>                       
                            </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-center">    
                                <span><b>Bank Name : </b>'.$row['bank'].'</span>                       
                            </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-center">    
                                <span><b>Cheque Number: </b>'.$row['cqn'].'</span>                       
                            </div>
                        ';
                    } if($row['payment']=="Credit Card"){
                            echo    '
                            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
                                <br>
                            </div>    
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-center">    

                                <span><b>Paid By: </b>'.$row['payment'].'</span>                       
                            </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-center">    
                                <span><b>Bank Name : </b>'.$row['bank'].'</span>                       
                            </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-center">    
                                <span><b>Credit Card Name: </b>'.$row['ccn'].'</span>                       
                            </div>
                        ';
                    } if($row['payment']=="Debit Card"){
                            echo    '
                            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
                                <br>
                            </div>    
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-center">    

                                <span><b>Paid By: </b>'.$row['payment'].'</span>                       
                            </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-center">    
                                <span><b>Bank Name : </b>'.$row['bank'].'</span>                       
                            </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-center">    
                                <span><b>Debit Card Name: </b>'.$row['dcn'].'</span>                       
                            </div>
                        ';
                    }

                     echo '

                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
                            <hr></hr>       
                        </div>

                                <span class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                                <img src="images/gym.png" width="50px" height="50px"> 
                                <b>Gym : </b>'.$row['gym'].'</span>                 
                                <span class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                                <img src="images/ca.png" width="50px" height="50px"> 
                                <b>Cardio : </b>'.$row['cardio'].'</span>                 
                                <span class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                                <img src="images/s.png" width="50px" height="50px"> 
                                <b>Steam : </b>'.$row['steam'].'</span>                 
                                <span class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                                <img src="images/sauna.png" width="50px" height="50px"> 
                                <b>Sauna : </b>'.$row['sauna'].'</span>         

                                <span class="col-lg-3 col-xs-3">
                                <img src="images/steam.png" width="50px" height="50px"> 
                                <b>Spa : </b>'.$row['spa'].'</span>                 
                                <span class="col-lg-3 col-xs-3">
                                <img src="images/diet.png" width="50px" height="50px"> 
                                <b>Diet : </b>'.$row['diet'].'</span>                 

                                <img src="images/train.png" width="50px" height="50px"> 
                                <span><b>Trainer : </b>'.$row['trainer'].'</span><br>
                               </div>
                                <div id="rules" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="display:none">
                        <hr>
                        <h6 class="text-center">Rules and Regulations</h6>
                        <ul style="font-size:10px">
                            <li>We reserve the right to admission.</li>
                            <li>Membership fees are non-refundable.</li>
                            <li>The rates for the facility may be changed at the sole discretion of Management without prior notice.</li>
                            <li>The management is not responsible for any loss or theft of members belongings.</li>
                            <li>We advice members not responsible not to carry valuables to the gym.</li>
                            <li>Smoking, chewing of Beetle Leafis strictly prohibited in the gym premises.</li>
                            <li>Courteous member conduct is very important in order to provide everyone with a pleasant workout experience. Poor conduct includes, but is not limited to : use of profanity, bad mouthing others and fighting. If a member is found treating anyone disrespectfully, their membership will be terminated without refund and that member waives their right to recourse.</li>
                            <li>Sports wear is compulsory in the gym.</li>
                            <li>Members must carry a separate pair of training shoes to be changed into the gym premises to help maintain hygiene.</li>
                            <li>The Management will maintain a notice board for intimidating the members of any future changes.</li>
                            <li>The Management expects the members to read it on regular basis. We assume the members read the notice.</li>
                            <li>We request members to use a deodorant spray.</li>
                            <li>Taxes are applicable.</li>
                        </ul>
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                    <div id="signature" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="display:none;">Authorised Signature <input type="text"> <span style="float:right">Customer Signature <input type="text"></span></div>
                   </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <span class="col-lg-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
                            <a href="'.$row['id'].'" class="freeze" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#freezeModal">FREEZE ACCOUNT</a>
                        </span>
                        <span class="col-lg-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
                            <a href="'.$row['id'].'" id="preview" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#previewModal">PREVIEW HISTORY</a>
                        </span>

                        <span class="col-lg-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#renew">RENEW/UPGRADE</a>
                        </span>
                         <span class="col-lg-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#transfer">ACCOUNT TRANSFER</a>
                        </span>
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
                          <p></p>
                         </div>
                    </div>                                                                     
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>';
}
```

I know there are questions related to this but i tried almost everything and nothings working yet

When i click on the a tag it targets a modal the info on the Modal is Displayed by AJAX and data interchanged by JSON

But when i want to open the modal once again the modal backdrop gets darker and darker.

Comment: <div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div> the opacity is 0.5 n gets overlayed

Comment: How are you closing the modal? Sounds like the backdrop is never removed from the DOM, so you end up with a new one each time, resulting in it being *darker and darker* so to speak.

Comment: i am closing the modal by clicking outside the modal

Comment: i havnt written any code for it though